# Display HTML in the page title

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
<script>

document.title = unescape("My Text<sup>&trade;</sup> For you");


</script>
```

Expected output: My Text ™ For you

Actual: My Text<sup>&trade;</sup> For you

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page title doesn't accept HTML, you should be using the actual Trademark symbol `™`